# Black spot in middle of Sun Disk when using Sky Texture, v2.90.0

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, world, skybox

Unsure if this is a bug or if I am doing something incorrect.

I have a World set up with a Background Sky Texture, with the following settings:

[image]

When rendering out the environment, no matter the position of the sun/camera etc., the sun has a small black spot in the center:

[image]

[image]

**I am aware that the version of Blender is still in alpha**, but is there a reason for this? It seems as though the center is almost too bright for the camera sensor (but the digital equivalent).

Comment: Have you tried it on other Blender versions? eg, 2.83.2 (latest official version)

Comment: @RichSedman unfortunately using this particular Sky texture style (Nishita) is brand new to 2.90.0, and so I can't compare.

Comment: Ah. In which case most likely a bug or a problem with the texture - as you say, possibly a point too bright for Blender to cope. You could raise it as a bug on the Blender developer website.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I have submitted it [here](https://developer.blender.org/T78842) and hopefully will find a solution soon!

Comment: After I reduced the Strength plus intensity and also increased a bit the sun, worked fine for me!